# How to apply if condition in GPU DataFrame- cuDF to filter the DataFrame?

Tags: rapids, cudf

I'd like to filter a cuDF data frame based on a column value, and then create a new column based on a condition specified. Basically, how can I apply the following in cuDF?

`df.loc[df.column_name condition, 'new column name'] = 'value if condition is met'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Given Pandas in cuDF

```
# value to be replaced in series 
value = 'value if condition is met'
# condition to qualify for replacement
mask = df.column_name condition

# https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/stable/
df['new column name'] = df.masked_assign(value, mask)
```

#### Applied Example

```
"""explanation: 
  >> if there is no pool, pool_sqft should be 0
"""

# value to be replaced in series 
value = 0
# condition to qualify for replacement
mask = df_train['pool_count']==0

# https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/stable/
df['pool_sqft'] = df.masked_assign(value, mask)
```

Answer (score 0):

While `masked_assign` works for certain conditions, `applymap` is [syntactically better and functionally similar to the Pandas API](https://rapidsai.github.io/projects/cudf/en/0.8.0/api.html?highlight=applymap#cudf.dataframe.series.Series.applymap).

Also, @ashwin-srinath mentions that `__setitem()__` is coming the 0.9 release, so you'll just be able to do `df[condition] = value`. `masked_assign` might be going away in favor of just `__setitem()__` as `masked_assign` is not a Pandas API function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.query()`

Example:

```
expr = "(a == 2) or (b == 3)"
filtered_df = df.query(expr)
```

where `a` and `b` are the names of the columns in the dataframe.